How to maintain type safety with a factory pattern and generic base class?
I'm working with TypeScript and trying to implement a factory pattern with a generic base class. I'm running into type inference issues when trying to use the methods of the dynamically created class. Here's a simplified version of my code:
abstract class BaseClass<TArg> {
  async getArgsArray(): Promise<TArg[]> {
    return await fetch("...").then(resp => resp.json()) as TArg[]
  }
}

type Class1Arg = { myValue: string }
class Class1 extends BaseClass<Class1Arg> {
  methodWithArgs(args: Class1Arg[]) {
    return args[0]?.myValue
  }
}

type Class2Arg = { myOtherValue: string }
class Class2 extends BaseClass<Class2Arg> {
  methodWithArgs(args: Class2Arg[]) {
    return args[0]?.myOtherValue
  }
}

async function getFactoryKey(): Promise<"class1" | "class2"> {
  return await fetch("...").then(resp => resp.json()) as Promise<"class1" | "class2">
}

const classes = {
  class1: Class1,
  class2: Class2
}

function factory<K extends keyof typeof classes>(
  key: K
): InstanceType<(typeof classes)[K]> {
  const TransformerClass = classes[key]
  return new TransformerClass() as InstanceType<(typeof classes)[K]>
}

async function test() {
  const key = await getFactoryKey()
  const myClass = factory(key)
  const args = await myClass.getArgsArray()
  
  // This line gives a TypeScript error
  myClass.methodWithArgs(args)
}

The issue occurs in the test function. TypeScript is giving me this error:
Argument of type 'Promise<Class2Arg[]> | Promise<Class1Arg[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Class2Arg & Class1Arg'.
Type 'Promise<Class2Arg[]>' is not assignable to type 'Class2Arg & Class1Arg'.
  Property 'myOtherValue' is missing in type 'Promise<Class2Arg[]>' but required in type 'Class2Arg'.

I understand that TypeScript is having trouble inferring the correct type for myClass and args, but I'm not sure how to fix this while maintaining the flexibility of the factory pattern.
How can I modify this code to maintain type safety and eliminate the TypeScript error, while still allowing for dynamic class creation based on a runtime value?

What is myClass.getArgsArray()?

There might be a problem inside a generic function that TypeScript won't know the concrete arguments type will fit the concrete method type. However, the type error you posted has nothing to do with that: it complains about arrays and promises

This is essentially ms/TS#30581; you need to refactor to generics in a particular way, such as the version shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?
